# templated function pointer, is this possible?

Tags: c++

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<unsigned> 
Traverse
(
unsigned    start_node, 

std::priority_queue
< 
    std::pair< unsigned, unsigned >, 
    std::vector< std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> >, 
    bool(*T)(const unsigned&, const unsigned&) 
> &pQueue
) const;
```

The above code basically doesnt compile. I think its syntax error with the following line:

```
    bool(*T)(const unsigned&, const unsigned&)
```

What is the correct syntax?

Thanks.

edit:
@ James, 
This is the declaration of a const class member function template.
The function takes the following arguments

1) an unsigned int

2) a priority_queue, sorted in an arbitrary manner specified by the client

The function returns a vector of unsigned ints.

Comment: In order to give the correct syntax, I'd have to know what it is supposed to mean.  The expression you've written doesn't have any meaning in C++, at least as far as I can see.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't make sense.  What are you trying to express with that line?  What are you trying to do with `T`?

Comment: and what is that line supposed to mean ?

Comment: @James:  I read it as this.  He is trying to implement a `const` member function template, called `Traverse`, which takes 2 parameters (an `unsigned` and a `std::priority_queue`), and returns a `vector<unsigned>`

Comment: @ James and vBx: I added a comment in the question about what the code is supposed to do. does this help?

Comment: what is not clear is what `T` is doing in that function pointer declaration. Do you want that `bool(*)(unsigned&,unsigned&)` function to be a member of `T` somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<unsigned> 
Traverse
(
unsigned    start_node, 

std::priority_queue
< 
    std::pair< unsigned, unsigned >, 
    std::vector< std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> >, 
    T
> &pQueue
) const;
```

Comment: If the function is called as `Traverse<int>` then, how will we mention that `priority_queue<>`s 3rd parameter is a function pointer. It will be simply passed as `int` and that will defeat the purpose.

Comment: @iammilind - I'm not entirely certain what OP's purpose was, so I admit that my code might defeat it. However, I'm pretty sure that invoking `Traverse<int>(a, b)` will produce a compile error of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need a function pointer as a template argument? `std::priority_queue` expects a function class (like less<> that has an operator() defined), not a C-style function pointer.

The following code will not work, even without a template argument:

```
bool(*fn)(const unsigned&, const unsigned&) = 0;

std::priority_queue<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>,
    std::vector<std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>>, fn> q;
```

What you need to do, is what Rob has suggested:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<unsigned> 
Traverse
(
unsigned    start_node, 

std::priority_queue
< 
    std::pair< unsigned, unsigned >, 
    std::vector< std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> >, 
    T
> &pQueue
) const;
```

Where T is the Comparer type.

Answer (score 1):

Is `Traverse` a stand alone function ? If yes then you should remove `const` in the very end. It compiles with that change. Also change `(*T)` to simply `(*)`.

If it's a member of a class then also it should compile.

Answer (score 1):

[Derived from here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t638232-priority_queue-predicate.html).

priority_queue accepts a function pointer for the compare argument, but you'd have to pass the function pointer to the constructor, not the template. The template would just accept the type of the function pointer.

The easiest way to implement this would be to use a functor (function object, predicate class or however you name it).

From that functor, you could also call the function pointer, provided it is known globally at compile time. But I assume it isn't so you might have to go the 'pass function pointer in constructor' route after all.

If the function address is known at compile time:

```
typedef bool (*MyFuncPtr)(const unsigned&, const unsigned&);
MyFuncPtr globalPtr = myCompareFunction;

struct MyCompare {
    bool operator()(const unsigned &a, const unsigned &b) const {
        return globalPtr(a, b);
    }
};

std::vector<unsigned> 
Traverse
(
unsigned    start_node, 
std::priority_queue
< 
    std::pair< unsigned, unsigned >, 
    std::vector< std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> >, 
    MyCompare 
> &pQueue
) const;
```

If it isn't:

```
typedef bool (*MyFuncPtr)(const unsigned&, const unsigned&);
typedef std::priority_queue
< 
    std::pair< unsigned, unsigned >, 
    std::vector< std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> >, 
    MyFuncPtr 
> MyQueue;

std::vector<unsigned> 
Traverse
(
unsigned    start_node, 
MyQueue     &pQueue
) const;

int main() {
    MyQueue queue(myCompareFunction);
    Traverse(..., queue);
}
```

In short, the template is pretty much useless here, because a function is not a type, and the type of the compare function is 100% predetermined (it's MyQueue). The compiler wouldn't have any information to infer a specific type from the arguments passed to Traverse().

If you don't actually need to change the comparison function dynamically during runtime, the other answers here are the way to go. Just pass T as the third template argument to your priority_queue.

Comment: I tried implementing something similar to your suggestion with the typedef bool (*MyFuncPtr)(const unsigned&, const unsigned&);. However it will fail when called with the following code: 

std::priority_queue< std::pair <unsigned, unsigned>, std::vector < std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> >, std::less < std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> >> myQueue;

return Traverse(start_node, myQueue);

The idea I need here is for the comparison function to be different for every queue passed to traverse. This does work as expected when just using T as the third argument for the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Your edit helps some.  There's still the problem that
`std::priority_queue` isn't a type, so you can't declare
a function using it.  But since you've already got a template,
the simplest solution would be:

```
template<typename T, typename Q>
std::vector<unsigned>
Travers( unsigned start_node, Q& pQueue ) const;
```

Trying to restrict `Q` to a set of instantiations of
`priority_queue` can doubtlessly be done, but it will be tricky;
you'll probably need some sort of template wrapper class with
template template parameters and partial specialization.